# What’s the ruling on praying without paying attention?

Tags: salat

If one doesn’t pay attention to certain points while praying, does that mean that his prayers won’t be accepted at those points?

Answer (score 1):

Bismi Allah Ar Rahman Ar Rahim.

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

All Perfect Praise be to Almighty God,

and prayers and peace be upon the Messenger of Allah and his family and companions,

Having said that,

Peace be upon those who follow guidance

If you want the prayer to be accepted then you should pay attention.

The prayer isn't "not accepted" as much as it is disliked, in fiqh (the human understanding of the divine Islamic law as revealed in the Quran and the Sunnah) they use the term "مكروه" in Arabic language which means disliked.

when you are praying you should be devout and focused on the prayer and abandon any unnecessary movements. Some people may play with the watch or with their hair or with their nose or with some of their clothes. This is contrary to what was ordered to be calm and tranquil in the prayer , this tampering is "disliked" except for a need and if it is a little. However, tampering with the many consecutive things invalidates the prayer making it not acceptable. The believer should exercise the reverence and strive to be humble in his prayer.

The Prayer is one of the situations that the believer is obliged to concentrate and gather his mind in it, his prayers for his God in the prayer (salat) and in verbal prayer (Dua'a), that's for the great sake of who he prays for him or calls him, and for the accuracy of the reward for what is issued from him at the time.
This refers to the meaning of humbleness (devoutness-reverence), which God praised the believers for it in Quran.

God Almighty said :

> ("And seek help through patience and prayer. And it is difficult, except for the devout.Those who know that they will meet their God, and that to Him they will return.")(Surat Al-Baqarah:45-46)

and said:

> ("Successful are the believers. Those who are humbled in their prayers.")(Surat al-Mu'minun:1-2)

But can each person achieve in his prayers all the total devoutness-humbleness-reverence (tranquility) that is interrupted by thinking in this life issues, and can every worshiper be serene and peaceful in the indulgence and harmony with the great spiritual position he is in i.e the prayer.

This devoutness-humbleness-reverence (tranquility), if it can be achieved by some of  the believers, or in some prayers without others, it is difficult for other people, and difficult in all prayers, evidence of this; what was reported about the Messenger Allah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)"

Prophet Muhammad -prayers and peace of Allah be upon him- said :

> "If the call to prayer -Adhaan- is made, the devil runs away and has a voice that comes out of him so that he doesn't hear the adhaan. If the adhaan is completed he comes back, then if call to prayer -Iqamat Assalat- started he runs away again and comes back when it's completed,until he comes between a man and his self (in his thoughts)and says: 'Think of such and such, think of such and such,' which he was not thinking about before, until the man does not know how much he has prayed."

It has been proven in the Sahihin that the Shaytaan was exposed to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) so that his prayer would be cut off but he couldn't.

And which helps the worshiper to avoid distraction, inattention and negligence is sensing the greatness of God and fear of him if he was negligent in his prayers, and sensing hope in his mercy and grace, and the shyness to be preoccupied of other than him.

And pushing away those thoughts can be done by removing the causes and sources, and these may be external causes such as the severe voices of radio and cars in the streets and markets and so on, and the treatment is to be far as possible from these sources. As well as the beautiful scenes such as inscribed tapestry,carpet,etc.. and pictures or drawings in front of the worshiper, and the treatment is to be removed or covered, and helps to achieve the devoutness while praying is to focus attention to the place of 'Sujud' i.e the place where you will face when prostration in the prayer, and to be close to the wall so that you are not occupied by any concern, and not pay attention, etc., which distracts focus.

It is known from the above that the reverence in prayer requires a continuous pursuit, and whatever its consequences, the worshiper has a reward, even if he does not reach the ultimate humbleness. The first is: reward for what came on the tongue of the worshiper of the dikhr (mentioning Allah) and reading (of Quran) and on the capturing of himself in prayer from the work and issues of this life for the Hereafter, and the second: The hope to Succeeding in his pursue for this humbleness, the vastness of the attempt May lead to the required reverence or close to it.

and God knows best.